# --host flag for ./configure when compiling for cortex m4

Tags: gcc, arm

I am compiling a library for ARM, however the configure file requires a --host option for cross-compiling.

In a normal simple situation I would compile using

```
CC = arm-none-eabi-gcc

CFLAGS =--specs=nosys.specs -Wall -O2 -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mthumb -mfloat-abi=hard -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -ffast-math
```

I tried `./configure --host=arm-none-eabi-gcc`

But that gives
`checking host system type... Invalid configuration arm-none-eabi-gcc: machine arm-none-eabi not recognized`

I also tried `--host=armv7e-m`

I tried searching for a list of hosts, but they are old/not maintained/not complete:
https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-3.3/buildstat.html
https://gcc.gnu.org/install/specific.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually the `--host` specifies the system on which the compiler will run. The system for which the generated cross-compiler will generate code for is called the `--target`. For example, if you're planning to run your cross-compiler on an x86_64 Linux box you may need something like `--host=x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`.
To select a bare-metal arm target you probably want to specify `--target=arm-none-eabi`.

Look here https://gcc.gnu.org/install/configure.html for examples of how GCC can be configured (though it's admittedly not a complete guide).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/autoconf.git/tree/build-aux/config.sub, I can use `armv7`. Seem to translate to `armv7-unknown-none`